# How should association changes be handled in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Let's say that I have an app with two collections: `Users` and `Tasks`. There's a many-to-many association between these -- a task can be associated with any number of users, and vice-versa. What would be the best way to handle a new association?

One approach is to assign a new collection of tasks for each user:

```
Users = Backbone.Model.extend({
  this.tasks = new Tasks;
  ...
});
```

then do `this.tasks.create()` with the model (or a copy) as the input.

The problem with this is that the task should already have an id. If a model has an id, Backbone wants to do an update. So rather than something like this:

`POST /users/156/tasks`

You get something like this:

`PUT /users/156/tasks/15`

Which is not what you want. You can just redefine the `isNew()` function for that model to get Backbone to do a POST, but that seems like a hack.

Another approach is to maintain a list of ids on either end. For example, the `User` model JSON could look like this:

```
{
  username: "jsmith"
  name: "Joe Smith"
  tasks: [5, 15, 256]
}
```

Just grab the ID from the model you want to add, and do a PUT on the user.

The problem here is that more data is sent over the wire, and the specific change is not represented. The server has to do more work to filter through the model, figure out what changed, and add/remove associations as necessary (the backend here is SQL, so we're not just dealing with embedded task lists or anything). It seems much better to request the specific association change that is needed.

So which approach seems best? Is there another alternative I'm not considering?

(Note: I would like to avoid Backbone extensions like Backbone-relational)

Comment: You could keep things stateless and just fetch for the tasks collection per use with the options.data hash.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why would a task have an id when you create one

Comment: it all depends what you are doing with it, depending on the event's you bind to, the code that gets executed on certain events, might be a performance hit if you have a collection as sub argument for every user, though i have no hard confirmed data on that. I'm wondering why the choice to avoid backbone-relational?

Comment: @Uzi tasks have ids, in the app this example is based on, because they've all been persisted to the server.

Comment: @Sander backbone-relational looks like it introduces a fair amount of additional complexity and magic; I'd like to avoid introducing another hurdle for other devs (and myself) to understand the app.

Answer (score 1):

For these cases I create a specific route that deals with the **relations** and not with the objects they self, for example:

```
POST /users/156/tasks_relations
```

Using this approach we are closer to a pure REST API due in fact what we are doing it not *CREATING(POST)* a `Task` but *CREATING(POST)* a `TaskRelation`.

In Backbone I also have an specific `TaskRelation` Model that represents the relation:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var TaskRelation = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: function(){
    return this.user.url + "/tasks_relations";
  },

  initialize: function( opts ){
    this.user = opts.user;
  }
});
```

So in the `User` we can sending a new `TaskRelation` to the server like this:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  addTask: function( task ){
    var task_relation = new TaskRelation({ user: this, task_id: id });
    task_relation.save();
  }
})
```

The server will take the `task_id` parameter and will do its business.